My USDC was filtered by the Token Holder
I know someone asks this question here, but I still can't understand it.
My USDC was in POLYGON, and I sent it to USDC ETH without knowing it. Now I can't find my coin. Is there any chance that I can recover my coin?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
